# How to write the wedge product in terms of Levi-Civita symbol

Tags: differential-geometry, notation

Suppose we are in 3 dimensional space  and that we  have a one form $E_i$ and a two form $\omega_{jk}$.The wedge product between these forms is $$(E\wedge \omega ) _{ijk}=E_i \omega_{jk}-E_j \omega_{ik}+E_k \omega_{ij}.$$

Is there a way to write this formula in a compact notation using the Levi-Civita symbol $\epsilon_{ijk}$?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Assuming 3D?

Comment: I will edit my question

Comment: This should be on Math.SE

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to introduce the $\varepsilon_{m_1\dots m_d}$ symbols to make wedge products in components notation. It is given by anti-symmetrization:

$$
[\omega_{m_1\dots m_k}]\wedge[\eta_{n_1\dots n_l}]=[\omega_{[m_1\dots m_k}\eta_{n_1\dots n_l]}]
$$

Now, if you want to raise and lower the indices you can use the Levi-Civita symbol. This is convenient since as $k$ and $l$ become big the redundancy of the description increse. For $d=3$ we can replace $k=2$ and $l=2$ by

$$
\omega^m=\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{mnp}\omega_{np},\qquad \eta^m=\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{mnp}\eta_{np}
$$